# Construct PVRTC mipmaps texture using array of textures?

Tags: mipmaps, pvrtc

How to construct PVRTC mipmaps texture using array of textures for every mipmap level different texture?

eg.
2048.png level 0
1024.png level 1
.
.
2.png    level 10
1.png    level 11

I need mipmap texture with PVRTC compression for my OpenGL ES2.
I was googling and I had no luck looking.
The only solution was to edit DDS and convert to PVRTC. 
The problem is that NVIDIA edit for DDS are for windows and I am on OSX.

Dose anyone have an idea how to avoid win.
Or some c/c++/objective-c open-source code that will help me construct mipmaps that I can convert in PVRTexTool that support .ktx .dds

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Install PowerVR Insider SDK from http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-insider.asp (needs registration).  Open PVRTexToolGUI and load your 2048.png (biggest map), generate mipmaps chain and in Surface Browser (tab on left side) unfold mipmap level.  On right mouse button there is "Load file to surface".